# HttpHandler [Image] cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, image, c#-4.0, httphandler

Ok i have been working non stop on this and doing a lot of searching.  I cannot get my images to display when pulling them from the database.  If i try going to the handler link manually i get a message saying "The image [Image] cannot be displayed because it contains errors".  I had some old images in the database from before and it first displayed those correctly.  But now if i update images it will give me this error when trying to view them.

Upload code.

```
if (fileuploadImage.HasFile)
        {
            if (IsValidImage(fileuploadImage))
            {
                int length = fileuploadImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];
                HttpPostedFile img = fileuploadImage.PostedFile;
                img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);

                if (mainImage == null)
                {
                    ProfileImage image = new ProfileImage();
                    image.ImageName = txtImageName.Text;
                    image.ImageData = imgbyte;
                    image.ImageType = img.ContentType;
                    image.MainImage = true;
                    image.PersonID = personID;

                    if (image.CreateImage() <= 0)
                    {
                        SetError("There was an error uploading this image.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mainImage.ImageName = txtImageName.Text;
                    mainImage.ImageType = img.ContentType;
                    mainImage.ImageData = imgbyte;
                    mainImage.MainImage = true;
                    mainImage.PersonID = personID;

                    if (!mainImage.UpdateImage())
                    {
                        SetError("There was an error uploading this image.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SetError("Not a valid image type.");
            }
```

Here is my image handler:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int imageid = Parser.GetInt(context.Request.QueryString["ImID"]);
        ProfileImage image = new ProfileImage(Parser.GetInt(imageid));

        context.Response.ContentType = image.ImageType;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(image.ImageData);
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

And this is how i'm calling it "~/ImageHandler.ashx?ImID=" + Parser.GetString(image.ImageID)

I'm using the data type Image in sql server to store this.

Edit:

I also found out that if i put a try catch around context.Response.end() it is erroring out saying the "Unable to evaluate the code because the native frame..."

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I was checking the header of the actual file to make sure it was valid.  Somehow that was altering the data and making it bad.

Comment: Perhaps the MemoryStream wasn't being reset to its original position?